# Variable of a template class with a template class template parameter set to a base template of the derived template with the variable

Tags: c++, templates

I'm attempting to have a derived class (normal template) that has a variable of a template type that has as its template class parameter the type of a base class (normal template, same parameter as the derived class) of the derived class (the one with the variable).  This makes VC++ incredibly angry at me, and I am incapable of calming its fury.  Here's a quick example:

```
template<template<typename VT> class CT, typename VT> struct encapThing {};

template<typename VT> struct innocuousBase {};

template<typename VT> struct derivOfDoom : public innocuousBase<VT>
{
    encapThing<innocuousBase, VT> ohgodhelp; //C3200
};
```

It will throw a C3200, saying it expected a class template.  Now, I can see why this might be thinking there is a recursive loop of templates within templates, even if this isn't *actually* the case.  How can I convince VC++ otherwise?

Comment: Compiles perfectly fine for me, VS 2010 SP1.

Comment: Weird, maybe I need to update.  Checked my example and it definitely doesn't compile.  I knew something was fishy about this!

Comment: @user: Which VS version are you using?

Comment: VC++ 2010, no SP1, gonna grab that now

Comment: I'm still struggling to read the title.

Comment: @Dennis: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/825823#825823

Comment: Oh btw, removed the `[casting]` tag since this got nothing to do with casting. :)

Comment: @Xeo : Doesn't compile for me, same version. How odd...

Comment: +1 for the best title of the day! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unqualified use of `innocuousBase` inside of `derivOfDoom<>` is interpreted as `innocuousBase<VT>`, much as unqualified use of `derivOfDoom` in that context would be interpreted as `derivOfDoom<VT>`. I don't remember offhand whether or not this is standard-conformant behavior, but the workaround is trivial: fully qualify `innocuousBase` so the compiler knows you're referring to the `innocuousBase` class template and not the `innocuousBase<VT>` base class:

```
template<typename VT> struct derivOfDoom : innocuousBase<VT>
{
    encapThing<::innocuousBase, VT> ohgodhelp;
};
```